# Get api keys from azure key vault, for mongodb atlas provider in Terraform

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform

I'm using Terraform to deploy a mongodb atlas instance on azure, but now I have to use the API keys to authenticate the mongodb provider in Terraform, but this is not really safe looking to me, so I want to put them in a key vault. But now it's unclear to me how I can read out the keyvault at the moment that the provider is constructed in Terraform.

With variables it's working:

```
provider "mongodbatlas" {
  public_key  = var.mongodb_atlas_api_pub_key
  private_key = var.mongodb_atlas_api_pri_key
}
```

But I would like it that I can get those secrets from key vault.

Answer (score 1):

When using Terraform, you have two primary strategies for retrieving secrets such as API keys from Azure Key Vault:

1. External CLI Commands: Fetch the secrets via Azure CLI commands before running Terraform, and then pass them as variables
   to your Terraform configuration. This method keeps the secrets out
   of the Terraform state file but requires careful handling to avoid
   exposing them in your shell history or logs.
2. Terraform Data Sources: Use the azurerm_key_vault_secret data source
   to fetch the secrets directly within your Terraform configuration.
   This method is simpler and more self-contained, but the secrets will
   be stored in the Terraform state file.

Regarding the Terraform state file, it's important to note:

Terraform state files are designed to track the state of your resources, and this includes data retrieved through data sources. Therefore, if you use Terraform to retrieve secrets, those secrets will be stored in the state file.
While Terraform providers can mark data as sensitive to prevent it from showing in the console output, sensitive data will still be present in the state file in plaintext. This is true for secrets retrieved from Azure Key Vault with the azurerm_key_vault_secret data source.
Given the potential sensitivity of data in state files, it's crucial to store your state files securely. If using remote state, ensure it's in a secure, access-controlled, and encrypted storage solution. If it's local, ensure it's in a secure environment and consider encrypting the file at rest.

Here's an example of how you can structure your Terraform files to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault and use those within the MongoDB Atlas provider:

azure.tf (Azure Provider and Key Vault data sources)

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features = {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "your_key_vault_name"
  resource_group_name = "your_resource_group_name"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "mongodb_public_key" {
  name         = "your-mongodb-public-key-secret-name"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "mongodb_private_key" {
  name         = "your-mongodb-private-key-secret-name"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

mongodb_atlas_provider.tf (MongoDB Atlas Provider)

```
provider "mongodbatlas" {
  public_key  = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.mongodb_public_key.value
  private_key = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.mongodb_private_key.value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respons, but my issue doesn't lie with getting secrets from the keyvault, sorry for the confusion. 
The issue is that for setting up the MongoDB Atlas provider, you need both keys, but if you try to read them from a vault, they only get read after the providers are initialised. So, to late it seems.